# Show that$(\sin x + 2 \cos 2x)(2\sin 2x - \cos x) < 4.5$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, contest-math

> $(\sin x + 2 \cos 2x)(2\sin 2x - \cos x) < 4.5$

This is a problem from [Algebraic Inequalities](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-77836-5).

Here is my idea:

$(\sin x + 2 \cos 2x)(2\sin 2x - \cos x) = 2 \sin2x \sin x - \sin x \cos x + 4 \sin 2x \cos 2x - 2 \cos 2x \cos x$.

So this can be equal to $2\sin 4x -2 \cos 3x - \frac{1}{2} \sin 2x$.

I have tried and searched this for a few hours, but got no suitable direction.

If anyone has a nice solution, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Triangle inequality immediately gives you $\leq$.  Now just check $=$ cannot occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{a} = \sin x + 2 \cos 2x$ and $\sqrt{b} = 2\sin 2x - \cos x$
Then, $$a + b = (\sin x + 2 \cos 2x)^{2} + (2\sin 2x - \cos x)^{2}$$
$$ = 1 + 4 + 4(\cos 2x \sin x - \cos x \sin2x)$$
$$= 5 +4(\sin(2x-x))$$
$$= 5 - 4\sin x$$
$$\leq 9$$
Note that the equality occurs when $\sin x = -1$. In that case, $$2\sin 2x - \cos x = 4\sin x\cos x - \cos x = 0$$  $(\because \cos x =0) $

Which is already satisfying our original inequality in the problem.So we only focus on the strict inequality cases.

So we get $\frac{a+b}{2} < \frac{9}{2}$.  Thus by AM-GM inequality, $$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} \leq \frac{a+b}{2} < \frac{9}{2}$$ Which is the required result

Comment: Note: OP claims they need strict inequality.